# How Can I Change Default Reply ToEmail

Tags: wp-mail, phpmailer

I want to set the SMTP settings manually instead of using a plugin. I did this using this [resource](https://gist.github.com/butlerblog/c5c5eae5ace5bdaefb5d). However, there is a problem.
If the user clicks "Reply", a different e-mail appears. Probably I've described this before with the plugin. However, I cannot remove it. If I make a new definition as below, it creates a new reply e-mail. Therefore, the past is not erased.
What I want: If the user clicks to reply to the incoming e-mail, only smtp_from e-mail should appear.

My Codes:

wp-config.php

```
define ('SMTP_FROM', 'example@example.com');
...
```

function.php

```
add_action ('phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example');
function my_phpmailer_example ($phpmailer) {
$phpmailer-> From = SMTP_FROM;
 
//My new definition. 
$phpmailer->addReplyTo('example@example.com ',' Information ');
...
}
```

Comment: Try with the [`wp_mail_from` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#usage) instead.

Comment: I'll try thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your setup and other specifics to your use case, you may want to clear any previous reply addresses.  You can do this with `$phpMailer->ClearReplyTos()`.  For example:

```
add_action ('phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example');
function my_phpmailer_example ($phpmailer) {
    $phpmailer->ClearReplyTos();
    $phpmailer->addReplyTo('example@example.com', 'EXAMPLE');
}
```

Also, if your example code in your question is exactly what you're using, you need to be careful of a few things:

1. Make sure your variables are right.  For example, the argument in your function is `$ phpmailer` <-note the space  If you have it like that, that could be the source of your problem.  Fix the space (i.e. `$phpmailer`)
2. The line for your `$phpmailer->AddReplyTo()` is commented out. Is that intentional?  With the comment ("//"), that line will not doing anything.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much. 1-) Probably happened while copy-pasting (I fixed it). 2-) Yes, I wrote it in the "comment line" to explain it(Added new comment).